# Change file name of image path in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, filenames, filepath

For example if I have the following paths:

> /upload/images/2018/01/01/thumbnail.jpg
>   /upload/images/2017/12/29/image.png

I would like to change them to:

> /upload/images/2018/01/01/thumbnail_small.jpg
>   /upload/images/2017/12/29/image_small.png

Is there a short way to do this?

Comment: are these paths hard coded in javascript or you get them from database?

Comment: How about `replace(/thumbnail/g, 'thumbnail_small')`

Comment: @ cdoshi I get from database

Comment: @  sideroxylon I just edited the post. The filename is not always `thumbnail`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out an answer for my question but don't understand how it works

```
var str = '/upload/images/2018/01/01/thumbnail.jpg'  
alert(str.replace(/(?=\.[^.]+$)/g, "_small"));
```